# scala implicit causes StackOverflowError

Tags: scala, stack-overflow, implicits

How does this implicit val cause a StackOverFlowError?

(pared down my original code, to still cause the error)

```
object Complicit {
  // a class with name, default, and conversion function as implicit val
  case class CC[A](name: String, defaultValue: A)(implicit val convert: String => A) {
    def getFrom(s: String): A= try { 
      convert(s) 
    } catch { 
      case t: Throwable => 
        println("ERROR: %s".format(t))  // just to see the StackOverflowException
        defaultValue
    }
  }  

  // this works fine
  object Works {
    val cc1= CC("first", 0.1)(_.toDouble)
  } 

  // this causes java.lang.StackOverflowError due to the implicit
  object Fails {
    // !!! StackOverFlowError here
    implicit val stringToDouble: String => Double= { _.toDouble }

    val cc2= CC("second", 0.2)
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    // this works
    println("%s %f".format(Works.cc1.name, Works.cc1.getFrom("2.3")))
    // this fails
    println("%s %f".format(Fails.cc2.name, Fails.cc2.getFrom("4.5")))
  }
}
```

Am I doing something illegal with implicits?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe I can answer what's happening here.. it's related to other implicit conversions, and the one you just created. If you add this trace you can confirm what stack overflow usually relates to  - a function calling itself repeatedly until the stack space of java crashes:

```
implicit val stringsToDouble: String => Double= { x=>println("called inner "+x); x.toDouble }
```

....
called inner 4.5
called inner 4.5
called inner 4.5
called inner 4.5
called inner 4.5ERROR: java.lang.StackOverflowError

I think what's happening is this - toDouble is not a natural function of java string, but rather happens using an Implicit conversion in StringOps (or StringLike, I'm not really sure but it's the same issue).

So when you call toDouble - the compiler starts seeking an implicit conversion that could contain the function "toDouble". In theory it could be any resulting class.

BUT - what should happen if several implicit conversions could achieve this? Unfortunately, "Double" also contains the function toDouble as proven here:

```
val x = 44.4
x.toDouble
```

And guess what? That means your new implicit function, now closest in scope wins the contest and get's called in a circle to accomplish "toDouble" - effectively trying to turn the string into a double, in order to call toDouble (on the class Double), repeatedly.. I'll admit it's fairly confusing, but the evidence fits.

Here's the fix.. it fits the explanation and prevents the recursive calls.

```
 implicit val stringsToDouble: String => Double= { java.lang.Double.parseDouble(_)  }
```

Comment: Does anyone know if this qualifies as a bug worth submitting? It seems to me the scope of an implicit conversion, should not be valid within the defining code of that conversion. (thus, always excluded). The only result that could ever come of allowing this, would always be an infinite loop

Comment: I took a chance this might be worth addressing and submitted the issue..   Scala Programming Language /  SI-7693

Comment: I think it is more fair to say Scala did just what was it was asked to do (i.e. not a bug).  Good to submit the issue and see what happens.  Maybe there is a clever way to detect and warn the user.  But, the problem is there could be any amount and complexity of code before the recursion.  Also, maybe someone wanted that recursion and has coded an exit condition.